# There is no implicit reference conversion from StatelessService to 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.IService'

Tags: azure, communication, microservices, azure-service-fabric, stateless

I am writing a new azure service application which can communicate using service remoting.
I referenced [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting). I am facing error:

> The type 'PushMsgStatelessService.PushMsgStatelessService' cannot be used as type parameter 'TStatelessService' in the generic type or method 'ServiceRemotingExtensions.CreateServiceRemotingListener(TStatelessService, StatelessServiceContext)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'PushMsgStatelessService.PushMsgStatelessService' to 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.IService'. PushMsgStatelessService C:\Nirvana\DataPerPerson\Narendra\PushMessageService\PushMsgStatelessService\PushMsgStatelessService.cs 30  Active

My code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Fabric;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Runtime;
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime;
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Runtime;

namespace PushMsgStatelessService
{
    interface IPushMessageService
    {
        Task<string> GetMessageAsync();
    }        

    /// <summary>
    /// An instance of this class is created for each service instance by the Service Fabric runtime.
    /// </summary>
    internal sealed class PushMsgStatelessService : StatelessService, IPushMessageService
    {
        public PushMsgStatelessService(StatelessServiceContext context)
            : base(context)
        { }

        public Task<string> GetMessageAsync()
        {
            return Task.FromResult("Hello!");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Optional override to create listeners (e.g., TCP, HTTP) for this service replica to handle client or user requests.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A collection of listeners.</returns>
        protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
        {
            return new[] { new ServiceInstanceListener(context => this.CreateServiceRemotingListener(context)) };
        }
    }
}
```

I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a reference to the `IService` interface in your interface. So change your `interface IPushMessageService` to `interface IPushMessageService : IService`.

Side node 1: You should probably make your interface public.

Side node 2: It is better to put your interface in a separate project to prevent any circular dependencies when working with remoting.